# Wordpress site links stopped working

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have been working on my wordpress site with the DUNAMIS theme, and all of a sudden the front page Rev. Slider, the links, Audios stopped working.

[Christarmenianchurch.com](http://www.christarmenianchurch.com)

These few errors that I see on the console

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$(document)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'audio.load')
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue. It was a plugin I had installed

Comment: Do specify name of the plugin which was causing this, so that people who might have same issue and find this question know what is causing it